# Error in my XML template in android studio which make render preview not be appear

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am working on an android studio app. and I've problem in previewing the render in the IDE. can somebody please provide me a solution ?

code here

in my XML file. i have no error and the application is running weel but the problem is when I open te previewer which show me there are error in rendering
XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#fff"
  android:minHeight="500dp">

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:textColorHint="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/dw_backgroun_edit"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:importantForAutofill="no" />

  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_transactions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:paddingVertical="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edittext_search" />

  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/button_add_transaction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_money"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tint="@color/white"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is the code of the error shown in the render panel and it indicates that the error is in a java file that is not editable: TextView.java

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:361)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:727)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:883)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.fonts.Font_Builder_Delegate.createBuffer(Font_Builder_Delegate.java:52)
    at android.graphics.fonts.Font$Builder.createBuffer(Font.java:264)
    at android.graphics.fonts.Font$Builder.<init>(Font.java:200)
    at android.graphics.Typeface$Builder.<init>(Typeface.java:517)
    at android.graphics.Typeface_Delegate.createFromDisk(Typeface_Delegate.java:99)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getFont(ResourceHelper.java:488)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getFont(ResourceHelper.java:500)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getFont(BridgeTypedArray.java:723)
    at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:4087)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1125)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:87)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:83)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:96)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:91)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:216)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:133)
    ... 27 more
```

[image: andoid studio screenshots]